# Powershell - Copying CSV, Modifying Headers, and Continuously Updating New CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

We have a log that tracks faxes sent through our fax server. It is a .csv that contains Date_Time, Duration, CallerID, Direction (i.e. inbound/outbound), Dialed#, and Answered#. This file is overwritten every 10 minutes with any new info that was tracked on the fax server. This cannot be changed to be appended.

Sometimes our faxes fail, and the duration on those will be equal to 00:00:00. We really don't know if they are failing until users let us know that they are getting complaints about missing faxes. I am trying to create a Powershell script that can read the file and notify us via email if there are n amount of failures.

I started working on it, but it quickly became a big mess as I ran into more problems. One issue I was trying to overcome was having it email us over and over if there are certain failures. Since I can't save anything on the original .csv's, I was trying to preform these ideas in the script.

- Copy .csv with a new header titled "LoggedFailure". Create file if it doesn't exist.
- Compare the two files, and add different data (i.e. updates on the original) to the copy.
- Check copied .csv for Durations equal to 00:00:00. If it is, mark the LoggedFailure header as "Yes" or some value.
- If there are n amount of failures, email us.
- Have this script run as a scheduled task (every hour or so).

I'm having difficulty with maintaining the data. I haven't done a lot of work with scripting or programming, so I'm having trouble with making the correct logic. I can look up cmdlets and understand them, but my main issue is logic. Does anyone have any tips or could provide some ideas on how to best update the data, track failures as to not send duplicate information, and have it run?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a hash table with the Dialed# as the key. Create PSCustomObjects that have LastFail date and FailCount  properties as the values.  Read through the log in chronological order, and add/increment a new entry in the hash table every time it finds an entry with Duration of 00:00:00 that's newer than what's already in the hash table.  If it finds a successful delivery event, delete the entry with that Dialed# key from the hash table if it exists.

When it's done, the hash table keys will be a collection of the Dialed numbers that are failing, and the objects in the values will tell you how many failures there have been, and when the last one was.   Use that to determine determine if an alert needs to be sent, and what numbers to report.

When a problem with a given fax number is resolved, a successful fax to that number will clear the entry from the hash table, and stop the alerts.

Save the hash table between runs by exporting it as CLIXML, and re-import it at the beginning of each run.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I was able to use something similar to get it to work.